# Eclipse Marketplace error - Unexpected exception: org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor

Tags: eclipse, ide, fedora, eclipse-marketplace

I'm on Fedora 24 and installed Eclipse Neon via the software shop. The Eclipse version is 4.6. build id: Z20160714-1910.

When trying to start the Marketplace, I get the following error after the Marketplace window pops up:

```
Unexpected exception: org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor
  org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor
    org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor
    org/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor
```

The only other thing installed is PyDev.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I ended up just downloading the tarball directly from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ and running the executable. Works just fine :)

Comment: @aiguofer thanks, will try that when I get back to Eclipse. Moved to another IDE for the moment....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the "Fedora Eclipse" group via dnf:

```
sudo dnf group install 'Fedora Eclipse'
```

I was getting the same error as you, and using the above fixed it for me. It must be that the rpm for Eclipse by itself (which is what the Software app would install) is missing some Fedora-related dependencies.